# let myUrl = URL(string: returns nil in swift

Tags: swift

```
    let adr = "http://www.dummy.com/mobil.aspx?id=\(uyeNo)&kaynak=ios\(ulke)&req=DB2021&list=\(liste)"
    let encAdr = adr.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) ?? ""
    let myUrl = URL(string: encAdr)
```

myUrl is always nil. I couldn't find the reason.

Comment: I get `Optional(www.google.com)` if I print it.

Comment: This is not how URLs are supposed to be encoded. You are never supposed to encode the whole URL.

Comment: I get an optional too.

Comment: I guess myStr isn't really "www.google.com"?

Comment: Still not reproducible, you should look at the variables you use when creating `adr` and see what they contains.

Comment: i would go further, and for debugging print adr to see what you're actually using

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I see String Interpolations in your URL string:

```
\(uyeNo) \(ulke) \(liste)
```

Have you assigned values on those three? If not, maybe that's the reason why your myURL value returns fatally nil.

Anyways, if above isn't necessarily your case, you may try the following code that may suit your need:

```
func myCompleteURL(uyeNo: String,ulke:String,liste: String) -> URL {
    let adr = "http://www.dummy.com/mobil.aspx?id=\(uyeNo)&kaynak=ios\(ulke)&req=DB2021&list=\(liste)"
    let encAdr = adr.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) ?? ""
    let myUrl = URL(string: encAdr)
    return myUrl!
}

func sampleCallFunction(){
    let url = myCompleteURL(uyeNo: "i",ulke: "love",liste: "cats")
    print(url)
    // Prints: http://www.dummy.com/mobil.aspx?id=i&kaynak=ioslove&req=DB2021&list=cats
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**try! this Updated Answer**

```
let urlString = "http://www.dummy.com/mobil.aspx?id=\(uyeNo)&kaynak=ios\(ulke)&req=DB2021&list=\(liste)"
let urlStringEncoding = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .alphanumerics) ?? ""
guard let url = URL(string: urlStringEncoding) else {
    return 
}
print(url)
```

Comment: OP has updated his question. This answer is no longer relevant